# Proving part c using parts a&b in a set of matrix exercises.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I have the following 3 problems, where u is a $n \times 1$ column vector and $A,B$ are $n \times n$ matrices. Furthermore, all entries are complex numbers.

a. Show that if $A$ is Hermitian, $u^{*}Au$ is real.

b. Show that $B^{*}B$ is Hermitian.

c. Prove that $u^{*}B^{*}Bu$ is real and non-negative.

I have proven parts a and b. Note that by combining them, we may almost get c (the realness follows, but not the non-negativity).

After starting c from scratch and trying to prove it from the definition of matrix multiplication, I haven't gotten anywhere. I'm wondering whether there is a simpler approach to part c that doesn't throw away all the work I've already done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have $x^*x=\sum_j\bar{x_j}x_j=\sum_j|x_j|^2\ge0$ for any vector $x$. Apply it for $x=Bu$.

---

Note that $\langle x, y\rangle:=x^*y$ is an *inner product*, the above can be rewritten $\langle x, x\rangle\ge0$ (which is an axiom for inner products, and it induces a *norm* $\|x\|:=\sqrt{\langle x, x\rangle}$), so that we have
$$u^*B^*Bu=\langle Bu, Bu\rangle=\|Bu\|^2\ge0$$

Comment: This is a nice solution, but why do we have $(Bu)^*=u^*B^*$?

Comment: On second thought, I think proving that would be simple, but then another question pops up: is this a notable property of conjugate transposition, or just something you happened to notice?

Comment: We have $(AB)^*=B^*A^*$ for every matrices. Note also we have $\langle Bx, y\rangle=x^*B^*y=\langle x, B^*y\rangle$ which is the identity of *adjoints*. So that, $u^*B^*Bu=\langle u, B^*Bu\rangle\ =\ \langle Bu, Bu\rangle$ by the adjoint identity.